# Java Timezone Formatting incorrectly (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ)

Tags: java, date, timezone

Timezone is not correctly formatted

```
    String fromDate = "2022-10-14T10:00:00+0300";
    final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(fromDate);   
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").format(date));
```

When run i am getting my local zone

```
2022-10-14T12:30:00+0430
```

Comment: and why is it *formatted incorrectly*"? (despite for using outdated classes, replaced by `java.time` classes, like for example `OffsetDateTime`) || A `Date` does not carry the time zone information and `SimpleDateFormat` uses the default time zone **if** no other is set - see [`setTimeZone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone))

Comment: I strongly recommend that you don't use `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` since those classes are troublesome and long outdated. Use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Answer (score 1):

Java `Date` has no concept of time zone and offset, it is actually an instant since the epoch and when you `toString()` it, it silently uses the default time zone for formatting. You already have an answer regarding the legacy API, so i'll post one about [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), the modern date-time API, available since java 8.

Parsing and formatting date/time is done with [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). The input string contains only offset, without timezone, in order to retain this information you need to parse it to [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
String fromDate = "2022-10-14T10:00:00+0300";
DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(fromDate, parseFormatter);
DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
System.out.println(outputFormatter.format(dateTime));
//prints - 2022-10-14T10:00:00.000+0300
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`   String fromDate = "2022-10-14T10:00:00+0300";
    final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
       
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(fromDate);   
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EAT"));
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));'
```